# Entity Framework Core Owned Type Value Object throws required Primary Key to be defined error when used with IdentityUser. Why?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, ef-core-2.2, value-objects, owned-types

I'm using EF Core 2.2. I have two context in my application. One is `AppIdentityDbContext` for identity related works and other is `AppContext` for app related works.

I have an identity user class - `ApplicationUser` - which has a relation to `Profile` entity from `AppContext` and the `Profile` entity in turn owns a value object `ProfileContact`.

Here is the code:

**ApplicationUser**

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid>
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Designation { get; set; }

    public Guid ProfileId { get; set; }
    public Profile Profile { get; set; }
}
```

**Profile**

```
public class Profile : BaseEntity<Guid>, IAggregateRoot
{
    private Profile()
    {
        // required by EF
    }

    public Profile(string brandName, ProfileContact profileContact)
    {
        BrandName = brandName;
        ProfileContact = profileContact;
    }

    public string BrandName { get; set; }

    public ProfileContact ProfileContact { get; private set; }
}
```

**ProfileContact**

```
public class ProfileContact // ValueObject
{
    private ProfileContact()
    {
        // required by EF
    }

    public ProfileContact(string email, string phone, string mobile)
    {
        Email = email;
        Phone = phone;
        Mobile = mobile;
    }

    public string Email { get; private set; }
    public string Phone { get; private set; }
    public string Mobile { get; private set; }
}
```

**IAggregateRoot**

`IAggregateRoot` is an empty interface used to restrict entities from using generic repositories in my project.

```cs
public interface IAggregateRoot
{
}
```

**AppContext**

Here is the 'Profile' Entity configuration in `AppContext`.

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<Profile>(ConfigureProfile);
}

private void ConfigureProfile(EntityTypeBuilder<Profile> builder)
{
    builder.Property(p => p.BrandName)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasMaxLength(50);

    builder.OwnsOne(p => p.ProfileContact);
}
```

I have configured `ProfileContact` as owned by `Profile` entity.

Now whenever user logs in, I get this error:

[image: > Error Description]

[image: > Error Stack]

Here is my login `Post` method. I'm using Asp.Net Core Identity scaffolded template.

**Login - OnPostAsync**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
{
   returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
       // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
       // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
       var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.MobileNumber, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);
       if (result.Succeeded)
       {
         ....

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return Page();
}
```

Does the value object/owned type needs an key to be defined? What I read and understood about `OwnedTypes` is that they belong to the same table but can be used as object. Am I doing anything wrong? or I need to add `Id` property to `ProfileContact`. If so why? Please assist.

Comment: What does `IAggregateRoot` look like? And are you sure `ConfigureProfile` is called?

Comment: `IAggregateRoot` is an empty interface to restrict entities from using generic repository. Yes `ConfigureProfile` is called in `AppContext`. I have updated the question with these information

Comment: I can't reproduce this. The only flaw in your code is that you don't call   `base.OnModelCreating(builder);` but that should raise other issues.

Comment: I have `base.OnModelCreating(builder)` in my `AppIdentityDbContext`. This needs to be added in `AppDbContext` as well? why to add that and what are all the other issues that will arise?

Comment: For now I tried adding `base.OnModelCreating(builder)` to my `AppDbContext` and that works. Bravo you helped me. Many Thanks. Please add this as answer along with what issues this will cause and the explanations. I'll mark it as answer.

Comment: OK, but if `AppDbContext` doesn't inherit from `IdentityDbContext` I don't see how the base call should be necessary.

Comment: my `AppDbContext` doesn't inherit from `IdentityDbContext`. But the issue is getting resolved only if I add `base.OnModelCreating(builder)` in my `AppDbContext`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this issue is happening if you have two separate context. One for Application and another one for Asp.Net Identity with customized ASP.NET Identity models. And that too with relations between entities in both context.

In that case, adding `base.OnModelCreating(builder)` in both the `context`'s `OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)` solves the issue.

Thanks [Gert Arnold](https://stackoverflow.com/users/861716/gert-arnold) for guidance and teaching. Credits to you.